# Laravel template not looping through array of views

Tags: php, model-view-controller, laravel, tumblr, laravel-4

Hoping this is some kind of silly oversight on my part, but I've had little luck finding information about this or other examples of similar usages of Laravel. I'm developing a Laravel 4 site whose content is populated not with a local database, but with posts from a specific Tumblr blog, via the Tumblr API.

Every Tumblr post has a certain type associated with it ("text", "video", "photo", etc.), and each type has entirely different types of content that need to be spit out, so I have a Blade template for each post type, inheriting from a master `post` Blade template. (Everything is just a stub right now.)

To fill out the front page, in my controller I'm populating an array with those post views (`$postViews`). What is maddening is that if I loop through `$postViews` and echo out each individual view *in the controller*, it contains the proper content--all three views in the array show up on the final site inside their correct templates.

But when I send `$postViews` off to my `welcome` view, and then loop through `$postViews` inside THERE, it renders three instances of ONLY the first view of the array. I have no idea why.

Here's the relevant code. As you can see in the welcome template, I tried looping through `$postViews` in the welcome view both with native PHP and with the Laravel template syntax. They both exhibit the same behavior: showing only the first of the three posts, three times.

```
// controllers/HomeController.php

class HomeController extends BaseController {

    public function showIndex()
    {
        $client = new Tumblr\API\Client(CONSUMERKEY, CONSUMERSECRET);
        $tumblrData = (array) ($client->getBlogPosts(BLOGNAME));
        $postViews = array();

        foreach ($tumblrData['posts'] as $post) {
            $post = (array) $post;
            $type = TumblrParse::getPostType($post);
            $postViews[] = View::make('tumblr.'.$type, array('post' => $post));
        }
        foreach ($postViews as $p){
            echo $p; 
                    // This works! It displays each post view properly before
                    // before rendering the welcome view, but I need them to 
                    // be inside the welcome view in a specific place.
        }
        return View::make('home.welcome')->with('postViews', $postViews);
    }


// views/home/welcome.blade.php

@extends('layouts.master')
@section('title')
    @parent :: Welcome
@stop
@section('content')
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
        <?php 
            foreach($postViews as $p) {
                echo $p; // Just outputs the first of the array three times
            }
        ?>
        @foreach($postViews as $p)
            {{ $p }} // Just outputs the first of the array three times
        @endforeach
@stop


// views/layouts/post.blade.php

<div class="post">
@yield('postcontent')
</div>


// views/tumblr/photo.blade.php
// Other post types have their own views: video.blade.php, text.blade.php, etc.

@extends('layouts.post')
@section('postcontent')
    <h1>This is a photo post!</h1>
    <?php var_dump($post); ?>
@stop
```

I really appreciate any help! I'm new to Laravel, which I'm sure is obvious. And for all I know, I'm doing something wrong in PHP generally rather than in Laravel specifically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this instance it probably makes sense to render each view as a string before appending it to the $postViews array using the view render method.

```
$postViews[] = View::make('tumblr.'.$type, array('post' => $post))->render();
```

Comment: That did it! It makes perfect sense now that you point it out. Since I had them rendering out properly in other contexts, it didn't occur to me to look for that View method. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

What about nesting views. Check documentation.

Comment: I looked at this but I didn't see any examples of binding distinct data to a potentially different nested view for each item in the array. I'm sure it's possible, but I didn't have any luck.